# CAkePHP: share blog content with authorized users only

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a site developed using CakePHP and the concept is to provide the user the ability to create 4 category of records that go into different tables and are backed by auth and acl, meaning one user cannot see the content created by others.

I want to provide an ability to the user where they can import cantacts from their gmail or any other email account and say only these people can access this particular record and send an email with the link to the content. The user should be forced to login with their email address before they can view content.

Do we have any plugins or sample snippets that I can  use to learn how to implement the same?

Comment: `The user should be forced to login with their email address before they can view content.` That's going to be a problem, as they are not actual users in your system (or you must be willing to create a new user with random pass for all entered e-mails). Creating a 'random' URL to the content without Authentication would be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple user management system that can be used for something like this if it helps:

https://github.com/cdburgess/SUM-Cake

It will prevent users from seeing data that does not belong to them. In addition it has admin access. Older versions support CakePHP v1.3.x. The latest code has been migrated to CakePHP v.2.0.x